# Berkeley DB Environment issues

Tags: c++, database, berkeley-db, nosql

So we're using the Berkeley DB, and our API uses the BDB C++ API. We recently added some new indexes on our database. After adding the new indexes, we needed to migrate all the old data to add the new indexes on the old records, and since then whenever we start up the process that writes to the database, we get these warnings:

BDB2058 Warning: Ignoring DB_SET_LOCK_TIMEOUT when joining the environment.
BDB2059 Warning: Ignoring DB_SET_TXN_TIMEOUT when joining the environment.

If I'm understanding those correctly, we now runt he risk of deadlocking since it's 'ignoring' the timeouts we set. I'm also seeing the process hang when trying to write tot he database randomly. The only way to get around it is to restart the process right now. My question is if anyone knows what would cause these warnings, or how I might go about debugging the Environment instantiation to find out? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout's are likely a persistent global attribute of the dbenv environment, not an attribute of each usage instance of a dbenv.

You might try running db_recover on the database to remove the __db.NNN files.

Otherwise you may have multiple processes sharing a dbenv and the warning is indicating that later processes are trying to change attributes that are already set.